# weird mapView overlay draw behavior when zooming out

Tags: mapkit, swift3, zooming, ios10, mkoverlay

This is what happens when I try to zoom out. this was not happening on ios9
and honestly I'm not sure what to look for.
the overlay is an MKGeodesicPolyline which i add to the mapview like so 
self.mapview.add(polylineOverlay).

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: nope, still happening (also in the simulator)

Comment: I was experiencing this issue too, but only when adding an MKOverlay onto the MapView. I moved my `mapview.add()` code into `viewDidAppear` which fixed it.

Comment: yeah, my situation is a bit different because I want to keep updating the overlays on the mapView and I'm not sure wether I should delete the other overlays before adding the new one (the new one will be the whole updated overlay) or keep the previous ones there and hoping that MapKit will do the right thing. I'm seeing this issue anyway though